# Common information model for SOA systems

Tags: web-services, architecture, soa

We are looking at the possibility of implementing a Common Information Model for data across several systems in a SOA architecture.

Many of these services will be consumed by a composite UI, we therefore see a benefit in having common data types.

What we are wondering is if this is a feasible approach, or if we should just map to common types in the client?

Comment: I always thought SOA was just a synonym for Highly Efficient Roaming Profile Emergence System . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a common information model doesn't imply common data types or common classes. Simply defining the relationships between, for instance, Customer, Order, OrderItem and Product goes a great distance toward common business logic and the ability to have different services and applications be able to interoperate in an SOA environment.

You might consider having an actual common model in some modeling language. From this, concrete data types and classes could be generated for particular circumstances. One might use UML for this, but I personally prefer to use [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx), an [Object-Role Modeling](http://www.ormfoundation.org/) tool. It works at the conceptual level, so creates models that are independent of the data store technology.

NORMA runs as an add-in to Visual Studio Standard edition or above, but out of the box generates artifacts for several databases, as well as LINQ to SQL classes and even PHP web services, all from the same model. It is extensible so that you can generate your own artifacts from the model. And of course, the model is represented as XML, so you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: John, Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555331/information-reuse-using-metadata-semantic-layer-in-soa ?

Comment: Thanks for your confidence, but I don't _have_ an answer for that one.

Answer (score 2):

This question is framed pretty broadly, so my answer is going to remain pretty broad as well.

The key consideration here would seem to be location independence - though you're working with several applications, they're all going to share certain sorts of data (though not, as far as I can see from your question, actual data). An obvious use case for this is authentication and authorization data.

If you have determined that the common data is truly cooked enough to isolate in the fashion you're describing then I think it makes perfect sense to layer it off into a service. I think the perfect example of this is [Windows Identity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351). It takes something that we as architects have always treated as data and turns it into a service.

What you lose with the location independence is a little bit of efficiency that you would otherwise have in making batches calls to the same server, though SOA applications lose this efficiency early in their design, in my experience. But the efficiency you gain from "patternizing" a section of your apps generally outweighs that enormously.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555331/information-reuse-using-metadata-semantic-layer-in-soa ?