# Information Reuse in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soa

While reading SOA articles I came across an article in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0806_boughannam/0806_boughannam.html . This explains about a Semantic/Logical service. There is an example of "request for organization data coming from sales department". This approach helps in overcoming the silos concept.

I was wondering whether there is any **WCF** implementation similar to the architecture mentioned in the article. Though I made some search, I could not find out one.
Could you please provide details of such an implementation or provide a reference to a similar implementation in WCF?

READING:

1. Enabling Business Capabilities with SOA
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/aa699435
2. Service Virtualization With The Managed Services Engine
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727511.aspx
3. [Managed Services Engine (MSE) Roadmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354516/managed-services-engine-mse-roadmap)

Answer (score 1):

Building a platform for Service Oriented Architecture usually involves several technologies to fulfill the different requirements involved. WCF could be a part of that solution to provide different transport and message format options for services involved, but would not suffice as the only basis to build the platform on.

The architecture in the article is a fairly standard service oriented one for larger corporations and can be implemented in a variety of technologies. I would suggest you that you search that space and read about the various tools to see what fits your needs. The Microsoft space for example include [Biztalk](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx), [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849), [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324), [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/), [SOA Governance](http://www.soa.com/), [Master Data Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/enterprise-information-management/master-data-management.aspx) and [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx). As SOA environments can be technology-agnostics, you could also browse other vendors or Open Source initiatives.